# Wifiphisher not creating a fake access point

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I recently came to know about [WifiPhisher](https://github.com/sophron/wifiphisher). To test it, I set up an access point using my Windows laptop and, tried to obtain its password using this tool in my Ubuntu machine. So, when I run the program, it can cause denial of service by sending deauth packets to the AP I have created, but it does not creates it fake access point, which can cause evil twin attack. So, does anyone know how to get around this ?

Comment: Have you tried this while using a third machine that is connected to the ap as a "victim". This is how it is supposed to be set up.

Comment: also, pineapple is good for doing this

Comment: Have you considered that Wifiphisher would required 2 wireless network adapters ?